# Client-Server, Object Input/Output, DeadLock

Tags: java, object, input, output, tcpclient

I am pretty new to writing client/server based apps. both server and client classes are kicked off in threads. New to using Object Output/input streams over tcp aswell. Have never had fun with serialization. In my application I am trying to use Object Input/Output Streaming but it looks like opening them is causing my application dies. The funny thing is that if I comment two lines:

```
outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Connection works nicely and app proceeds to the next panels etc. But I am still not capable of sending any objects throughout the socket. When I literally try to open those streams. It still connects but app get freezed. I 've got two questions:
first: is it better to use serialization
second: if I can use Object streaming, how should I open them? Can I do it inside the server/client thread?

Thanks for Your time

Here is the code of ClientApp:

```
public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try // odswiezanie co sekunde
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try // polaczenie
        {
            if (connecting)
            {
                socket = new Socket(hostIP, port);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection established!");
                connected = true;
                connecting = false;
                frame.settingPanelForClient.bPlayerName.setText("Put the ships on your board!");
                outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                connectionEstablished(frame);
            }
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Unknown server!");
            connected = false;
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"An Error occured while trying to connect to the server!");
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
            connected = false;
        } 
        catch (IllegalThreadStateException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try // odbior obiektow
        {
            if(connected)
            {
                while(!opponentIsReady){
                System.out.println("wszedlem do connected!(klient) ");
                System.out.println(opponentIsReady);
                if(!opponentIsReady)
                {
                    if(inStream.readObject() != null)
                     {
                         if(inStream.readObject() instanceof Boolean)
                         {
                             opponentIsReady = inStream.readBoolean();
                             System.out.println(opponentIsReady);
                         }
                         else if(inStream.readObject() instanceof Map)
                         {
                             mapToGet = (Map) inStream.readObject();
                         }
                     }
                }

                if(iAmReady && !opponentIsReady)
                {
                    System.out.println("wszedlem do iAmReady i wysylam wiadomosc o gotowosci do klienta!");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Waiting for opponent to finish");
                    outStream.writeObject(iAmReady);
                    outStream.flush();
                }

                if(opponentIsReady)
                {
                    sendMap();
                    proceedToNextPanel(frame);
                    opponentIsReady = false;
                }
            }}


        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just some context - [this is probably why your application freezes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29).

Comment: so thoughout the Object streaming I can send only a file that contains an object serialized into bytes right?

Comment: I just thought that it is good to point towards the documentation describing what is going on. How to solve it must be answered by someone else as I have zero experience with that :).

Comment: ObjectOutputStream and  ObjectInputStream is not thread safe,so when you are using across multiThread you need think about the scope of ObjectOutputStream and  ObjectInputStream as well as their task

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface for the **Map** object ?

If you still frozen at a step, its maybe because you try to read object (from server or client) and you didn't send it by the other side. While the object is not read it will wait for content.

I dont know how work your server, but you read response twice when `oppenentReady` is **`false`**.

```
    if (inStream.readObject() != null) {
        if (inStream.readObject() instanceof Boolean) {
            //...
        }
    }
```

If this is not the expected behavior, you should store it in local variable.

Comment: yep I have a separate class Map which implements Serializable so that every single new object of Map class has it. What is curious is the problem may be a listener. Probably I am trying to listen all the time, before the server answers, maybe that's the problem, will try to solve it and let u know, thanks for Your time:)

Comment: You can maybe use a communication sequence diagram to have a better understanding of the client/server communication. And don't forget to store your response in local variables. Because in the communication link between server and client when you are reading an object it will wait to consume this whole object.

Answer (score 0):

Once again, this's smt I want to implement(in steps)

```
1. user choose to open connection(he becomes a server and waits for a client
 to connect) - done.
2. second user choose to connect(becomes a client and connects to the 
second player(server) - done.
3. Both get message that the connection is established and they are moved 
to the next Panel where they do specific operations - done.
4.When anyone of them finishes, I want to tell it to the second guy
(it is represented by a boolean local varable) - here comes the problem.
5. When both have finished, they should be moved to the next Panel where
they play.(before they start playing, Maps that they have set in the previous Panel 
should be sent to each other.
```

Next steps I can handle if Only I knew maybe not how to send those informations 
but where to place sending code because it seems to be in the wrong place. Here is the full code of client/server classes:

connecting - is set to true in the other class after pushing the button.

iAmready  - is set to true when player finishes setting up the map and should be sent to opponent,
because it triggers a specific operation by setting opponentIsReady to true when obtained.

```
public class ClientApp implements Runnable
{
public static String hostIP = "127.0.0.1";
public static int port = 1000;
public static boolean connected = false;
public static boolean connecting = false;
public static boolean iAmReady = false;
public static boolean opponentIsReady = false;

public static Socket socket = null;
public static ObjectInputStream inStream;
public static ObjectOutputStream outStream;
public final Frame frame;
public static Map mapToGet;
public static Map mapToSend;


public ClientApp(Frame parent)
{
    frame = parent;
    mapToGet = new Map();
    mapToSend = new Map();
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try // odswiezanie co sekunde
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try // polaczenie
        {
            if (connecting)
            {
                socket = new Socket(hostIP, port);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection established!");
                connected = true;
                connecting = false;
                frame.settingPanelForClient.bPlayerName.setText("Put the ships on your board!");
                connectionEstablished(frame);
            }
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Unknown server!");
            connected = false;
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"An Error occured while trying to connect to the server!");
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
            connected = false;
        } 
        catch (IllegalThreadStateException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try // odbior obiektow
        {
            if(connected)
            {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/message.ser");
                outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/tmp/message.ser");
                inStream = new ObjectInputStream(in);

                while(!opponentIsReady){
                System.out.println("wszedlem do connected!(klient) ");
                System.out.println(opponentIsReady);
                if(!opponentIsReady)
                {
                    if(inStream.readObject() != null)
                     {
                         if(inStream.readObject() instanceof Boolean)
                         {
                             opponentIsReady = inStream.readBoolean();
                             System.out.println(opponentIsReady);
                         }
                         else if(inStream.readObject() instanceof Map)
                         {
                             mapToGet = (Map) inStream.readObject();
                         }
                     }
                }

                if(iAmReady && !opponentIsReady)
                {
                    System.out.println("wszedlem do iAmReady i wysylam wiadomosc o gotowosci do klienta!");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Waiting for opponent to finish");
                    outStream.writeObject(iAmReady);
                    outStream.flush();
                }

                if(opponentIsReady && iAmReady)
                {
                    sendMap();
                    proceedToNextPanel(frame);
                    opponentIsReady = false;
                }

            }
                inStream.close();
                outStream.close();
                in.close();
                out.close();
        }


        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public static void connectionEstablished(Frame frame)
{
    frame.remove(frame.connectPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(frame.settingPanelForClient);
    frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();
}

public static void proceedToNextPanel(Frame frame)
{
    frame.remove(frame.settingPanelForClient);
    frame.getContentPane().add(frame.opponentsMove);
    frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();
}

public static Map getMap()
{
    try
    {
        if (connected)

        if (inStream.readObject() != null && inStream.readObject() instanceof Map)
        {
            mapToGet = (Map) inStream.readObject();
            return mapToGet;
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void sendMap()
{
    if (connected)
        if (mapToSend != null)
        {
            try
            {
                outStream.writeObject(mapToSend);
                outStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

}

```
public class ServerApp implements Runnable
{
public static int port = 1000;
public static boolean connected = false;
public static boolean connecting = false;
public static boolean iAmReady = false;
public static boolean opponentIsReady = false;
public static Socket socket = null;
public static ServerSocket hostServer = null;
public static ObjectInputStream inStream;
public static ObjectOutputStream outStream;
public static Map mapToGet;
public static Map mapToSend;
final Frame frame;



public ServerApp(Frame parent)
{
    frame = parent;
    mapToGet = new Map();
    mapToSend = new Map();
}
@Override
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        try 
        { 
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        try 
        {
            if (connecting) 
            {
                hostServer = new ServerSocket(port);
                socket = hostServer.accept();
                connected = true;
                connecting = false;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Established!");
                frame.settingPanelForServer.bPlayerName.setText("Put the ships on your board!");
                connectionEstablished(frame);
            }
        }

        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            connected = connecting = false;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            connected = connecting = false;
        } 

        try // odbior obiektow
        {
            if(connected)
            {
                while(!opponentIsReady){
                System.out.println("wszedlem do connected(server)");
                System.out.println(opponentIsReady);
                if(!opponentIsReady)
                {
                    inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    if(inStream.readObject() != null)
                     {
                         if(inStream.readObject() instanceof Boolean)
                         {
                             opponentIsReady = inStream.readBoolean();
                             System.out.println(opponentIsReady);
                         }
                         else if(inStream.readObject() instanceof Map)
                         {
                             mapToGet = (Map) inStream.readObject();
                         }
                     }
                }

                if(iAmReady && !opponentIsReady)
                {
                    System.out.println("wszedlem do iAmReady i wysylam wiadomosc o gotowosci do servera!");
                    outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Waiting for opponent to finish");
                    outStream.writeObject(iAmReady);
                    outStream.flush();
                }

                if(opponentIsReady && iAmReady)
                {
                    sendMap();
                    proceedToNextPanel(frame);
                    opponentIsReady = false;
                }
            }}


        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void connectionEstablished(Frame frame)
{
    frame.remove(frame.waitPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(frame.settingPanelForServer);
    frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();
}

public static void proceedToNextPanel(Frame frame)
{
    frame.remove(frame.settingPanelForServer);
    frame.getContentPane().add(frame.playPanelForServer);
    frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();
}

public static Map getMap()
{
    try
    {
        if (connected)

        if (inStream.readObject() != null && inStream.readObject() instanceof Map)
        {
            mapToGet = (Map) inStream.readObject();
            return mapToGet;
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static void sendMap()
{
    if (connected)
        if (mapToSend != null)
        {
            try
            {
                outStream.writeObject(mapToSend);
                outStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As i said before, you can not use readObject() more than once for the same object.

Example,
Use:

```
Object objectRead=inStream.readObject();
if (objectRead != null) {
    if (objectRead instanceof Boolean) {
        opponentIsReady = Boolean.valueOf(objectRead);
        System.out.println(opponentIsReady);
    } else if (objectRead instanceof Map) {
        mapToGet = (Map) objectRead;
    }
}
```

Instead of:

```
if(inStream.readObject() != null)
{
    if(inStream.readObject() instanceof Boolean)
    {
        opponentIsReady = inStream.readBoolean();
        System.out.println(opponentIsReady);
    }
    else if(inStream.readObject() instanceof Map)
    {
        mapToGet = (Map) inStream.readObject();
    }
}
```

I think you didn't understand how it works:
When the client/server connection is etablished you can use Threads to read or write objects.

I give you code that you can test to understand how it works:

ServerApp:

```
public class ServerApp implements Runnable {

    public static int port = 1000;
    public static boolean opponentIsReady = false;
    public static Socket socket = null;
    public static ServerSocket hostServer = null;
    public static ObjectInputStream inStream;
    public static ObjectOutputStream outStream;
    public static Map mapToGet;
    public static Map mapToSend;
    final Frame frame;
    private boolean connected = false;

    public ServerApp(Frame parent) {
        frame = parent;
        mapToGet = new Map();
        mapToSend = new Map();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Server initialization side
        try {
            hostServer = new ServerSocket(port);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Waiting for opponent to finish");

            // Accept will wait until a client try to connect
            socket = hostServer.accept();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Established!");

            // Init streams when connection is etablished
            inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            frame.settingPanelForServer.bPlayerName.setText("Put the ships on your board!");
            connectionEstablished(frame);

            connected = true;

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerApp.class.getName()).log(
                Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        int x = 0;
        // The loop is made to send/receive all messages
        while (connected) {
            try {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ServerApp.class.getName()).log(
                        Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                Object o = String.format("I send you a message (%s)", x++);
                outStream.writeObject(o);
                Object response = inStream.readObject();
                System.out.println("Response: " + response);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerApp.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                connected = false;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerApp.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                connected = false;
            }
        }
        System.err.println("Connection closed");
    }

    public static void connectionEstablished(Frame frame) {
        frame.remove(frame.waitPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(frame.settingPanelForServer);
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
    }

    public static void proceedToNextPanel(Frame frame) {
        frame.remove(frame.settingPanelForServer);
        frame.getContentPane().add(frame.playPanelForServer);
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
    }

    public static Map getMap() {
        try {
            if (inStream.readObject() != null && inStream.readObject() instanceof Map) {
                mapToGet = (Map) inStream.readObject();
                return mapToGet;
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void sendMap() {
        if (mapToSend != null) {
            try {
                outStream.writeObject(mapToSend);
                outStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ClientApp:

```
public class ClientApp implements Runnable {

    public static String hostIP = "127.0.0.1";
    public static int port = 1000;
    public static boolean connected = false;
    public static boolean connecting = true;
    public static boolean iAmReady = false;
    public static boolean opponentIsReady = false;

    public static Socket socket = null;
    public static ObjectInputStream inStream;
    public static ObjectOutputStream outStream;
    public final Frame frame;
    public static Map mapToGet;
    public static Map mapToSend;

    public ClientApp(Frame parent) {
        frame = parent;
        mapToGet = new Map();
        mapToSend = new Map();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Client initialization side
            socket = new Socket(hostIP, port);

            // If the socket connection succeed it pass, else execption is thrown
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Established!");

            // Initialize streams
            outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            inStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            frame.settingPanelForClient.bPlayerName.setText("Put the ships on your board!");
            connectionEstablished(frame);

            connected=true;

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientApp.class.getName()).log(
                Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // The loop will receive server message and send response
        while (connected) {
            try {
                Object serverMessage = inStream.readObject();
                System.out.println("Server sent: " + serverMessage);
                Object myResponse = String.format("I received %s", serverMessage);
                outStream.writeObject(myResponse);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClientApp.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                connected=false;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClientApp.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                connected=false;
            }
        }
        System.err.println("Connection closed");
    }

    public static void connectionEstablished(Frame frame) {
        frame.remove(frame.connectPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(frame.settingPanelForClient);
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
    }

    public static void proceedToNextPanel(Frame frame) {
        frame.remove(frame.settingPanelForClient);
        frame.getContentPane().add(frame.opponentsMove);
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
    }

    public static Map getMap() {
        try {
            if (connected) {
                if (inStream.readObject() != null && inStream.readObject() instanceof Map) {
                    mapToGet = (Map) inStream.readObject();
                    return mapToGet;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void sendMap() {
        if (connected) {
            if (mapToSend != null) {
                try {
                    outStream.writeObject(mapToSend);
                    outStream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i got this, so now here is the deal, I need a mechanism that waits for the message, this message will be a boolean saying if the other side has finished setting up the board. and if it does it should trigger next steps. how to perform that? my current code looks like `while(true)` and inside i have 2 try catch blocks, the one responsible for connection works well, the second one that is responsible for listening is placed into the loop `while(!opponentIsReady)` and if he is ready or nto should be sent via socket! How to perform that?

Comment: I think the problem is on server side. When the second client is connected you must send `true` to the first client. On the first client side you should use a `inStream.readObject()` that will wait until the boolean is received.

Comment: this is exactly what I want to do and I knew that since I started implementing it. But I guess I am doing it wrong. When I start the server/client thread everything inside is going on inside the infinite loop but for example I cannot see the printline of the second try block dunno why because it is just after try. NO CONDITIONS before the println. and it should be printed every second because my first try block is Thread.sleep(1000).

Comment: thank You very much for your approach, will take a look immediately!

Comment: by the way, as you can see my server and client app classes are almost the same, just for the future, should I write an inerface and just implement it in those classes or should they extend a class called NetworkManager where I could store all that information that is the same in both cases?

Comment: Indead you should use an interface and if you want a class that can provide common code (read response, send request...). The part that you must understand is that the Thread must be use to read the response from the other side. The Client and Server themselves don't need to implement Runnable. But the method that will use `inStream.readObject()` must be inside a Thread that will treat the request. This part will be run on Client and on Server once they will be initialized.